# How to keep edible cookie dough soft after refrigerated?

Tags: cookies

I have experimented with about 5-6 edible cookie dough recipes. All are similar to regular cookie recipes minus the eggs and I also use heat treated flour to kill any bacteria. They all taste amazing but as soon as we place the bowl in the refrigerator it becomes rock hard. I need to find a way to keep it soft and scoopable after refrigeration. Any ideas what I could add?

Comment: Have you let it warm back up again? What are you doing with the dough? Is your fat butter?

Comment: How do you store it in the bowl? Uncovered, a lid? Try to keep air from the dough, e.g. by tightly wrapping in saran wrap.

Answer (score 1):

Since most recipes use butter, I'm going to guess that's what you're using.

Think about butter in the fridge... what's it like? It's hard. Stiff.

Well, that's why your dough is getting hard. So, you have a couple of solutions.

1. Replace the butter with a fat that's softer when cold instead of using butter. Perhaps coconut oil?
2. Portion the dough before you put it into the fridge and let your portion warm back up to room temperature before eating it.

For me, I'd go with option two because I'd be worried about the texture when the cookies *were* warm, which would be much softer than they are currently, and I'd be worried about changing the flavor. If you're using the dough in something really cold - like ice cream - then option 1 would probably be fine for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is to add water (or milk, or other liquid) to your cookie dough recipe.  This will make the dough extra soft when room temperature, so when it sets up as it cools, even the stiffer dough will be relatively soft and scoopable.

If you are intending to warm it to room temp before enjoying, you'd want to use only a little liquid (like, try adding tbs by tbs), so as not to dilute the flavor overmuch....and you may not need very much to soften it, either.  If you want to enjoy it straight from the fridge, you would want to add more water for a softer overall result.

Adding a bland ingredient like water will likely make the cookie dough a little less flavorful,  but the difference might not be great - depending on how much you add and how flavorful it starts out.  On the other hand, a softer dough will likely *seem* more flavorful than a drier one, as the flavors are more available to spread on the tongue - so there's usually quite a bit of wiggle room as to how much water you can add before it starts to taste watery.